# unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am getting image as base64 blob from a service and I am binding into
view. But I am facing an issue. How can I sanitize the url into a
trusted url. I have tried with sanitizer but no luck..

Please help me out..

**html code:**

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{inspectionDetails.reportImage}}" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Image" />
```

**ts code :**

```
this.ImgUrl = this.inspectionDetails.reportImage;
this.base64Image = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.ImgUrl);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to make this change

```
this.ImgUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.inspectionDetails.reportImage;
```

or

```
this.ImgUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${{this.inspectionDetails.reportImage}}`;
```

then Your HTML will be

```
<img [src]="ImgUrl " width="100%" height="100%" alt="Image" />
```

this should work

EDIT:

```
public ImgUrl = ' ';
```

Answer (score 45):

Use `_sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` to tell angular src value is safe

You can change your code like below.

Import DomSanitizer

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Inject this dependency into the constructor

```
constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }


myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
     this.base64Image = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(myReader.result);
     console.log(this.base64Image);
   }
```

Comment: @Mehdi Do you know how to use this in angular js?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize 
Will be very helpful dear

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced similar kind of issue for video and here's a way how I resolved it. You can set SRC in HTML like mentioned below to resolve unsafe data issue for image/video.

**[src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(src)"**

Comment: import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
Inject this dependency into the constructor

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { } --- Then it works fine and is very short

Comment: it must be set to public : constructor constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue manage to resolve with using [src] instead of src

code that didnt work

```
<img src=`{{recipe.imagePath}}` class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;">
```

fixed with

```
<img [src]="recipe.imagePath" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;">
```

where imagePath was just simple URL to some image from internet

Comment: the question was regarding binary image data, not URLs

Comment: @PaulG if you read the question again.... "How can I sanitize the url into a trusted url. I have tried with sanitizer but no luck.." Like I said, had same issue when I was learning angular